# Can CPU code exist under "with tf.device(gpu_id) :" in multiple GPU case?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

Hi I am new to Tensorflow and I am assigned a task to change the "Demo.py" in a Github project "tf-faster-rcnn" to achieve multi-GPU inferencing.

And this is generally what I plan to do (suppose the number of images I have is the same as the number of GPUs, and I will use a queue which is not illustrated here for simplicity reason):

```
for id, gpu in gpu_dict:
    with tf.device(gpu):
        im_detect(images[id])
```

The "im_detect" function is provided in the the source file (I can straight away call it) and it contains some non-GPU code (like conditions and data preparation)

```
def im_detect(sess, net, im):
  blobs, im_scales = _get_blobs(im)
  assert len(im_scales) == 1, "Only single-image batch implemented"

  im_blob = blobs['data']
  blobs['im_info'] = np.array([im_blob.shape[1], im_blob.shape[2], im_scales[0]], dtype=np.float32)

  _, scores, bbox_pred, rois = net.test_image(sess, blobs['data'], blobs['im_info'])

  boxes = rois[:, 1:5] / im_scales[0]
  scores = np.reshape(scores, [scores.shape[0], -1])
  bbox_pred = np.reshape(bbox_pred, [bbox_pred.shape[0], -1])
  if cfg.TEST.BBOX_REG:
    # Apply bounding-box regression deltas
    box_deltas = bbox_pred
    pred_boxes = bbox_transform_inv(boxes, box_deltas)
    pred_boxes = _clip_boxes(pred_boxes, im.shape)
  else:
    # Simply repeat the boxes, once for each class
    pred_boxes = np.tile(boxes, (1, scores.shape[1]))

  return scores, pred_boxes
```

Since I have never played with GPU before and I am a newbie to Tensorflow, I would like to ask is it okay to assign each GPU such a function call in Tensorflow?

----------------below is updated------------------------

I know there's a "alow_soft_placement" option in Tensorflow and that assigned those non-GPU code to CPU, but when there are multiple GPUs, how can one CPU handle those requests from all the GPUs? Should I create a CPU thread for each GPU?

Comment: Where are your TensorFlow ops defined in `im_detect`?  You won't be able to return your results directly from `im_detect` as it looks like you intend to.  When you set up the tf ops, they won't run until you call `session.run` subsequently (and presumably after looping over devices).  That being said, within a graph, multiple GPUs and a single CPU can work together.  Ops will need unique references though, so that there's no ambiguity about what's running where. So, for example GPU:0 might get data from a "data_prep_0" tensor on CPU, and GPU:1 would need to refer to a "data_prep_1" on CPU.

Comment: @JoshuaR. The sess.run(tensors) is called in the "test_image" function in the "im_detect" function (quite a long function call track in this case...). Thx for the help, looks like I don't have to worry too much about the concurrency here.

Comment: You won't be running the ops on both GPUs at the same time if you do that.  Your loop will wait for each session.run to complete to proceed to the next GPU device.  I'm adding a schematic code sample to my answer below which might structure things.

Comment: @JoshuaR.  Thanks for giving such detailed answer! https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py    This is a multi-gpu training example under Tensorflow, and I think it's the same idea as mine (using loop and only one session)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  From https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu.  The `allow_soft_placement` argument to your session configuration allows TensorFlow to fall-back to CPU if an op has no CUDA kernel.

```
myConf = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=myConf)
```

Sometimes you won't want this - e.g. if you're trying to verify all of the ops that you expect are actually running on GPU.

You can also explicitly assign ops to CPU using `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` inside of a `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` block.

I tend to prefer to use strict placement and then explicitly assign incompatible ops to cpu when TensorFlow complains.  That way I'm sure all the appropriate ops are GPU optimized.

UPDATE:

Here's a bit of schematic code which should outline how to get parallel calculations running on GPUs.

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

gpus = ['/gpu:0', '/gpu:1']
results = []
datasets = []

for idx, gpu in enumerate(gpus):
   with tf.device(gpu):
       # assign data prep ops to CPU
       # (or use soft placement and leave out the next line).
       with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            datasets[idx] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'Features'+idx)

       # Computationally expensive ops get assigned to GPU, but make reference
       # to specific non-GPU ops on CPU.
       results[idx] = tf.reduce_sum(datasets[idx])  

myConf = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)

with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=myConf) as session:

    # Now, using the graph set up previously, evaluate results
    # using both gpu devices (each these ops depends on independent
    # cpu ops).
    res0, res1 = session.run([results[0], results[1]])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! If I have 2 GPUs, when I assign both of them works  to do there should be 2 tensors flowing concurrently. But I only have one CPU to handle those non-GPU codes, should I assigned each GPU a CPU thread, or Tensor flow is able to handle that for me?

Comment: @JiangWenbo, That's an interesting question.  Are you running all of the devices in the same session?  I don't see where your session is defined.  Are your inference tasks unrelated (i.e. "embarrassing parallel"), or do you intend for you GPUs to work together on the same inference at the same time (i.e. a single graph distributed across them)?

Comment: yes I intend to run all the device in the same session, so everything will be under that session. Yes I am inferencing some test images (one GPU process one image at a time) which are unrelated.